# Unpredictable opacity behaviour in WPF fonts

Tags: wpf, colors, rendering, opacity

I have a problem understanding opacity in WPF. I have the code posted below. My questions are:

- Why do the rectangle and the font get different colors?
- Why do both TextBlocks get different colors, when I change the font size?

I would expect that, when I snoop the color with a color picker, black with an opacity with 50% would render #7F7F7F, but instead I get #C2C2C2 for the smaller TextBlock, and the expected #7F7F7F for the larger font and the rectangle.

Question has been partially asked at https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/issues/408 but not properly answered.

Any help is appreciated!

The code is:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfPlay.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfPlay"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="800" Background="White">

    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForeBrush" Color="Black" Opacity="0.5"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackBrush" Color="White" Opacity="1.0"/>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="TextBlockStyle">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForeBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="48"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="TextBlockLargeStyle">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForeBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="100"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="White">
        <TextBlock Text="Click me" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" Margin="20"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Click me" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockLargeStyle}" Margin="20"/>
        <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="20" Fill="{StaticResource ForeBrush}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why it happens, but I can verify the color changes at FontSize = 80 on my computer.

Comment: According to https://support.microsoft.com/nl-be/help/2712383/wpf-application-hangs-when-using-fonts-over-100pts-in-size, Net 3.5 is having difficulties with fonsizes of 100 and greater (specifically, when 100pts after transformations, dpi settings etc). Perhaps there is still some 'left-over' bug regarding opacity and fontsizes of 100pts and greater.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a workaround by setting the opacity on the complete TextBlock. This would of course also change the opacity of the backbrush, so it may not give the desired effect if you have a different StackPanel back color.

```
<TextBlock Text="Click me" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" Opacity="0.5"/>
```

But there is also the possibility to overwrite the ControlTemplate of a textblock and connect the opacity property to the foreground only.

Or you could make a Grid with inside a TextBlock, so you can set the opacity property on the TextBlock without touching the background of the rectangle it is sitting in.